# Help in writing a nasty expression in nice closed form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, closed-form, products

This question is abouting re-writing a product in nice closed form. I have the following
$$f(v_1) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^K \pi \lambda_i \delta_1  v_1^{\delta_1-1} P_i^{\delta_1} e^{-\beta_i (v_1P_i)^{\frac{\delta_1}{2}}}+ \pi \lambda_i \delta_2 v_1^{\delta_2-1}P_i^{\delta_2}(1-e^{-\beta_i (v_1P_i)^{\frac{\delta_2}{2}}})\right)  $$

$$ f(v_2|v_1)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^K \pi \lambda_i \delta_1v_2^{\delta_1-1} P_i^{\delta_1} e^{-\beta_i ((v_2-v_1)P_i)^{\frac{\delta_1}{2}}}  + \pi \lambda_i \delta_2 v_2^{\delta_2-1}P_i^{\delta_2}(1-e^{-\beta_i ((v_2-v_1)P_i)^{\frac{\delta_2}{2}}})\right)$$
where $ P_i,\beta_i,\lambda_i,\delta_1,\delta_2,K $ are all constants $\forall i$.
I have to write their product $$f(v_1)f(v_2|v_1)$$ in nice closed form.
I have done the following till now, 
$$\left(v_1^{\delta_1-1}v_2^{\delta_1-1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^K \pi \lambda_i \delta_1 P_i^{\delta_1}\right)^2 e^{-\beta_i (v_2P_i)^{\frac{\delta_1}{2}}}  + v_1^{\delta_2-1}v_2^{\delta_2-1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^K  \pi \lambda_i \delta_2 P_i^{\delta_2}\right) ^2(1-e^{-\beta_i (v_2P_i)^{\frac{\delta_2}{2}}})\right)$$

but I am still missing two terms within the product which are the cross terms - should the cross terms that be inside $\sum_{i,j}$, can anyone help me write it nice closed form

Comment: What is anything that you have written? What is $\delta, \pi, \lambda, K$ etc.

Comment: what do you mean?